# How to find specific class name in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new and start to learn writing html. In my code, the situation would be that when I click to a button, I used `$(event.currentTarget).parents('.page-container')` to get the whole html element of my currentTarget and then I have all elements like below:

```
<div class="page-container">
   <div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
      <div id="accordionSummaryList" class="sidebar-left col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas">
        <div class="mainTenant">
          <div class="subTenant">
             <h5 data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionSummaryList" href="#toggleAbleListGroup1">Admins</h5>                                                                     
             <div class="container-fluid panel-collapse collapse in" id="toggleAbleListGroup1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is I would like to find all of the div element which have the class = "collapse in" and I want to remove the class "in" to hide the content inside of this div box.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to find the element with a specific class name using jQuery?

Comment: yes I want to find a specific class name and then remove this class, for example, I want to find class collapse in and then remove class in

Comment: and one thing that I want to ask is : is it possible that I can find specific class name which located inside of specific element? In my case for example: the class "collapse in" located inside of div class "subTenant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vanilla-JS

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.subTenant .collapse.in'), function(el){
     el.classList.remove('in');
}
```

or with jQuery (if already included)

```
$('.subTenant .collapse.in').removeClass('in');
```

Comment: I suppose the difference in performance won't be noticeable for a single usage, anyway https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-array-prototype-foreach

Comment: Thanks for your answer fcalderan!. And one thing that I want to ask is : is it possible that I can find specific class name which located inside of specific element? In my case for example: the class "collapse in" located inside of div class "subTenant"

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with jquery

```
   jQuery('.collapse').removeClass('in');
```

Comment: you can directly use  jQuery('.collapse').removeClass('in');

Comment: hasClass check multiple class in full html and remove all "in" classs

Comment: But the logic you write is: IF any `div` element on the page has the class `.collapse` THEN remove the class `.in` from all elements with a `.collapse` class. The if is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with jquery: `$(".collapse.in").removeClass("in")`

Comment: Ah Andrew, and one thing that I want to ask is : is it possible that I can find specific class name which located inside of specific element? In my case for example: the class "collapse in" located inside of div class "subTenant"

Comment: Sure, you can try `$(".subTenant .collapse.in")` selector or in case that element with class name `subTenant` is direct parent element: `$(".subTenant > .collapse.in")`. The `>` symbol means children of parent, where parent is located before the symbol and children is after the symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with this

```
if($(event.currentTarget).parents('.page-container').find('.collapse'))
{
  $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
}
```

Comment: and one thing that I want to ask is : is it possible that I can find specific class name which located inside of specific element? In my case for example: the class "collapse in" located inside of div class "subTenant"

Comment: @Son, yeah it is possible you can find specific class name with the help of .find() function see this 

https://api.jquery.com/find/